# Visual Studio 2013 - Resharper. How can I restore the Visual Studio Code Snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

How can I stop Resharper hiding my Visual Studio 2013 code snippets.

I like the rest of Resharper but their code snippets are awfull and doesn't have "propdp".

I don't want to get rid of all the Resharper settings. Just the code snippets.

Comment: Actually, ReSharper's default behavior is to continue to support Visual Studio snippets even after ReSharper is installed. You might not see code completion for them, but pressing TAB should still invoke them.

Answer (score 4):

Enter - dep and press Tab. Resharper generated dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

If you knew what the 'propdp' snippet did then you can replicate it with Resharper's Templates (plus a lot more than the standard VS snippets). All of Visual Studio's snippets will have been converted to Resharper's Templates when you installed it however the 'propdp' one is not standard (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349402/missing-snippet-in-visual-studio) for details)

See [Resharper's Template help pages](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Index.html).